# pandas asype("datetime64") is not consistent and does not raise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have absolutely no idea on how to build a MWE for this because this behaviour happens when I slice my dataframe, see console output below:

First slice, I have `NaT`for the last rows:

```
In [161]: df.iloc[3802:11775].astype({"date": "datetime64"})[["date"]]
Out[161]:
          date
258 2014-09-14
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
..         ...
781        NaT
781        NaT
781        NaT
781        NaT
781        NaT

[7973 rows x 1 columns]
```

If I update the slice to start from 3803, it works well:

```
In [162]: df.iloc[3803:11775].astype({"date": "datetime64"})[["date"]]
Out[162]:
          date
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
259 2018-10-12
..         ...
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14

[7972 rows x 1 columns]
```

and id I concat first and last parts because I thought there might be something with the rows at id 3802, it still works:

```
In [165]: pd.concat([df.iloc[3800:3803], df.iloc[11770:11775]]).astype({"date": "datetime64"})[["date"]]
Out[165]:
          date
258 2014-09-14
258 2014-09-14
258 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
781 2014-09-14
```

I have to say that I have been using pandas for more than 3 years but here I am completely lost.

##### EDIT

I have added the series in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ClementWalter/fc8ca669175ab01cc4c6bb4e95165382)

The bug is visible in this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/167lnO3xJ3juOJNMy0SCYWKkBhSf0fBv6?usp=sharing) with pandas 1.3.0 and actually fixed in pandas 1.3.3

Comment: Have you manually inspected the values at those rows? Any chance you can paste-bin the data? I see you're working in iPython, is it possible you've got references to old data or other wonkiness going on? I realize I'm "have you tried turning it off and back on again?" right now, but I didn't immediately see anything wrong.

Comment: I have added the data in a gist. And I have tried from scratch with `read_csv` from this new extract file and still having the issue

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the provided data in pandas 1.3.3 perhaps this is version specific?

Comment: actually this colab with 1.3.0 does show the bug : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/167lnO3xJ3juOJNMy0SCYWKkBhSf0fBv6?usp=sharing

Comment: and no bug with 1.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce your error:

```py
In [31]: df = pd.read_csv("date_error.csv")

In [32]: df.iloc[3802:11775].astype({"date": "datetime64"})
Out[32]:
       Unnamed: 0       date
3802          258 2014-09-14
3803          259 2018-10-12
3804          259 2018-10-12
3805          259 2018-10-12
3806          259 2018-10-12
...           ...        ...
11770         781 2014-09-14
11771         781 2014-09-14
11772         781 2014-09-14
11773         781 2014-09-14
11774         781 2014-09-14

[7973 rows x 2 columns]

In [33]: df["date"].isna().any()
Out[33]: False
```

That said, I'd suggest using `pd.to_datetime` instead of `astype()`.

Comment: see added colab, not working with pandas 1.3.0 at but ok for 1.3.3, seems like a real fixed bug

Comment: side question: why should I prefer using `to_datetime`?

Comment: Hmm... I was under the impression that it had better performance but I may be wrong. At the very least, it's a bit cleaner. PS - you *can* actually parse those columns as dates [at the time of reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in your data (however I'm not sure if that's your current workflow).